# Laravel tinker text suggestion or autocomplete through the tab key

Tags: php, laravel, read-eval-print-loop, tinker

Is there any way to use <kbd>Tab</kbd> key to suggest or auto-complete text or predefined variables on **Laravel Tinker**?

Answer (score 1):

I've had this issue a few weeks ago but when i use php7.2* its solved.

its good to tell you i use zsh in ubuntu. but it works right in bash locating in windows wsl and bash in ubnutu too

[image]

Comment: I'm using `zsh` on ubuntu too, and also `php7.3.*`. I tried both in `zsh` and `bash shell`, but no suggestion yet.

Comment: which version of Laravel are you using ? i'm using 5.5.45 at this moment and i uncommented the section related to enabling bash completion which is locating in /etc/bash.bashrc

Comment: Nah, I have done that and no suggestions yet.
I am using Laravel `5.8.*`.